# Há alguma função para arrays no Java como o join() do PHP?

Tags: php, java, array

Existe alguma função no Java que é igual (ou semelhante) como a [join](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.join.php) do PHP? Se sim, demonstre sua utilização.

Comment: O que esse join faz? Junta dois arrays?

Comment: Verifique se isso responde sua pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join

Comment: @diegofm, junta 2 arrays em uma string

Comment: Essa tambem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195047/5524514

Comment: @diegofm, favor coloque sua resposta para #Velasco aceitar a resposta e assim fechar o tópico.

Comment: @Everson foi proposital postar o link como comentario. Se quiser responder, fique a vontade :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando o Java 8 você pode fazer isso de forma bem limpa e fácil com:

```
String.join(delimiter, elements);
```

Isso funciona em três maneiras:

1) Especificando diretamente os elementos

```
String joined1 = String.join(",", "a", "b", "c");
```

2) Utilizando array's

```
String[] array = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
String joined2 = String.join(",", array);
```

3) Utilizando iterables

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
String joined3 = String.join(",", list);
```

Se você estiver precisando para o android:

```
String android.text.TextUtils.join(CharSequence delimiter, Object[] tokens)
```

Exemplo:

```
String joined = TextUtils.join(";", MyStringArray);
```

Referência:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515437/java-function-for-arrays-like-phps-join

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp/26195047#26195047

Comment: Não esqueça de referenciar o post original dos links.

Comment: Atualizado!! :)